# T-test alternative for comparing two independent ordinal distributions

Tags: statistical-significance

I have users rate recommendations on a scale of 1 - 5.  The recommendations come from 2 different algorithms A and B. Let's say that A has got 300 ratings whereas B has got 160. Their means are pretty close. I want to check if they are statistically different. I know I can use the Students T test to test this, but it assumes normal distribution (ordinal in this case). Is there a better metric for this case?

Comment: Is the question you're interested in answering nearer to "does one tend to rate higher than the other"? (e.g. if you chose a random ratings each, to see whether one of them is more likely to get the higher rating than the other is) or is the question "are the rating distributions different in any manner?" (where you'd be able to pick up for example that one got more polarized ratings -- both high and low -- while the other had more middling ratings)

Comment: @Glen_b, I am interested in answering "does A tend to get higher ratings than B". I plotted both in a boxplot and they seem to be pretty close in terms of mean and variance, with one slightly higher than the other. More precisely, I am interested in confirming "A tends to have higher ratings than B as per this experiment, with confidence 95%"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the clarification in comments (about "tend to have higher ratings"), I'd lean toward something like the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test ([Mann-Whitney U-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) / Wilcoxon rank-sum test). It will not even require that the ratings be interval scaled (i.e. you don't have to assume that the difference between a 4 and a 5 is the same as the difference between a 2 and a 3, as you'd need to be able to take averages before a t-test could even make sense).

Indeed the Mann-Whitney U statistic measures tendency of one to be higher than the other in a pretty direct way.

Comment: This looks more appropriate than the T test for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shashank,

If I've understood you correctly, then you want to compare either (i) two distributions or (ii) the means of two distributions.

If you want to compare two distributions, then I suggest that you plot the histogram of each distribution and compare these to one another. I.e. what proportion of ratings was an 1,2,3,4,5 using Algorithm A and what proportion of ratings was an 1,2,3,4,5 using Algorithm B? You don't really need a statistical test to do this comparison. That's not to say that it is not possible, but eyeballing will probably do the trick for you.

If you want to compare the means of two distributions, then I suggest that you use student's T-test for the comparison of two means. There are two potential problems that I foresee in using this test.

One is that the ratings might be ordinal as opposed to interval. Ordinal means that the difference between 1 and 2 is not the same as the difference between 2 and 3. 2 is higher than 1 and 3 is higher than 2, but the distance between these is meaningless. An ordinal rating just tells you whether something is "better" or "worse" than something else. Interval means that the distance between the ratings does have the same meaning. The distance between 2 and 1 is 1. And the distance between 3 and 2 is 1. The distance is the same. To use student's T-test for two independent samples to compare means you have to assume that the ratings are interval variables. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to compute a mean.

Two is that the values can only take values from 1 - 5. This means that the maximal difference between the means is 4 or - 4. Whereas the distribution of the T-statistic is computed under the assumption that there is no such limitation. Some possibilities are therefore ruled out and the p-value will not be correct. Practically, however, this shouldn't matter.

As to the point that you cannot use a T-test. This is not correct. The difference between the means and the means themselves are random variables. These will differ from sample to sample (i.e. if you run the algorithms again on different data you will get different values). These random variables are approximately normally distributed according to the central limit theorem. Because you however don't know the variance of the population distributions you have to use the samples to estimate these. This estimate is another random variable. And in such a situation you use the T-distribution and the T-test instead of a Z-test.

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Toby. A boxplot of both the distributions looks pretty close to being the same, one having a slightly higher mean and variance than the other. I am now looking for a "significantly different test", and I thought if I could prove they are significantly different distributions, I can conclude that the distribution of the higher mean can be considered to be the better algorithm.  Regarding the means being normally distributed (random variables), that makes sense :) Thanks.

Comment: @Shashank, you can't conclude that because two things are different that one is better than the other. What's better depends on what purpose you wish to use those algorithms.

Comment: understood. Users rated samples based on a certain objective (how helpful recommendations are w.r.t. completing a coding problem), and I am only trying to infer which algorithm is better for that objective based on their ratings.